# NAB Transact - How to process a refund with Omnipay

Tags: php, omnipay

We are using Omnipay for NAB Transact.

https://github.com/sudiptpa/omnipay-nabtransact

We can successfully make payments and we can see amount in back with transaction id etc.

Now we are trying to refund so according to documentation its need below parameters
'amount', 'transactionId', 'transactionReference'

and our code is

```
$refund = $gateway->refund([
                   'transactionReference' => "XYZ100",
                   'transactionId' => "245294",
                   'amount' => "10.00"
                    ]);

$response =  $refund ->send();
```

In response we are seeing this message

```
Credit card details not available
```

Can some one help with it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _“so according to documentation”_ - where exactly? Supply links to the exact location, please, when you state stuff like this, so that we can go and check for ourselves.

Comment: Its from here , https://github.com/sudiptpa/omnipay-nabtransact

Comment: public function testRefund()
    {
        $request = $this->gateway->refund(['amount' => '10.00', 'transactionId' => 'Order-YKHU67']);

        $this->assertInstanceOf('\Omnipay\NABTransact\Message\SecureXMLRefundRequest', $request);
        $this->assertSame('10.00', $request->getAmount());
        $this->assertSame('Order-YKHU67', $request->getTransactionId());
    }